# Postfix is delivering all mail to 1@domain.tld

Tags: email, postfix

I am attempting to email an address on my own box (username@domain.tld), and postfix is attempting to deliver to 1@domain.tld - the username is replaced with the number 1.  This message is included in mailer-daemon's response:

`<1@domain.tld> (expanded from <user@domain.tld>): host mail.domain.tld[private/dovecot-lmtp] said: 550 5.1.1 <1@domain.tld> User doesn't exist: 1@domain.tld (in reply to RCPT TO command)`

Searching the mail log, the first result that refers to 1@domain.tld is this:

`Oct 19 13:41:44 servername postfix/lmtp[16232]: A547EC29C2: to=<1@domain.tld>, orig_to=<username@domain.tld>, relay=mail.domain.tld[private/dovecot-lmtp], delay=0.19, delays=0.16/0.01/0.01/0.02, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (host mail.domain.tld[private/dovecot-lmtp] said: 550 5.1.1 <1@domain.tld> User doesn't exist: 1@domain.tld (in reply to RCPT TO command))`

username@domain.tld exists, and can send mail outwards.  1@domain.tld does not exist, obviously.

So why is Postfix repeatedly delivering all mail to 1@domain.tld?

Answer (score 0):

Running `doveconf -n` to verify the confirmation revealed the following line:

```
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-email2email.cf
```

Checking `/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-email2email.cf` revealed the actual error:

```
query = SELECT 1 FROM virtual_users WHERE email='%s'
```

So, after carefully searching the database, it would select the number 1, for any user where the email was the given address.  To fix this, change `1` in the query to the actual proper column name your table uses.